# mysql result to multidimensional json array in different structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I am struggling to achieve the correct json array format from the mysqli resultset. I have googled extensively and tried different things.

I am sql querying e-commerce orders and attempting to output them in JSON format to post to an application, in the JSON format specified by the application developer.

First tried this, outputs each line separately , not what I want:

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $orders[]=$row; 
} 
echo json_encode($orders, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The result was

```
[
    {
        "WebOrderNumber_C": "938276",
        "itemName": "B3440S"
    },
    {
        "WebOrderNumber_C": "938276",
        "itemName": "D5035G"
    },
    {
        "WebOrderNumber_C": "938276",
        "itemName": "D6015"
    }
]
```

Second having googled again and read other questions on here, I tried this

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
$orders[$row['WebOrderNumber_C']][] = $row['itemName'];
} 
echo json_encode($orders, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The result was

```
{
    "938276": [
        "B3440S",
        "D5035G",
        "D6015"
    ]
}
```

The format I am trying to achieve is this. please help

```
{
    "WebOrderNumber_C": "938276",
    "shipAddress": {
        "add1": "LONDON"
    },
    "items": [{
            "itemName": "B3440S"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "B3440S"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "B3440S"
        }
    ]
}
```

PS I am Using PHP 5.6.30 if that is relevant.

Comment: Where does the shipping address come from?

Comment: @barmar sorry to cause confusion, it is another field in the resultset of the mysqli. I hadn't started including it in my experiments so far yet, but it is in the desired result. If someone can help in principle with what I have done wrong with the other elements I suspect I could extrapolate it to deal with the shipping address too. I hope :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array you're adding to is nested, you need to create the parent object the first time you encounter a row with that order number. You can use an associative array for that, to make it easy to tell if the object already exists.

Then you add to the nested array, and wrap the item name in the associative array with the `itemName` key.

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $orderno = $row['WebOrderNumber_C'];
    if (!isset($orders[$orderno])) {
        $orders[$orderno] = [
            "WebOrderNumber_C" => $orderno,
            "shipAddress" => [
                "add1" => $row["add1"],
                // other fields here ...
            ],
            "items" => []
        ];
    }
    $orders[$orderno]["items"][] = ["itemName" => $row['itemName']];
}
$orders = array_values($orders); // Convert from associative array to indexed
echo json_encode($orders, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, only the slight hitch that $orders[$orderno]]["items"][] has a surplus ] but hey no harm in checking I am paying attention properly at 3.23 am :-)

Comment: That was left over from when it was `$orders[$row['WebOrderNumber_C']]` and I missed deleting one of the `]`.

Comment: No problem. I am not complaining it was a great answer and really quick too. Thanks.